# Error with AsyncFileUpload in DotNetNuke

Tags: ajaxcontroltoolkit, dotnetnuke, asyncfileupload

Has anyone succeeded in using `AsyncFileUpload` in DotNetNuke? Although the module is marked as "allow partial render", I get two errors in web page, as alerts:

> Unhandled exception: Access is denied

and

> Unhandled exception: the requested file uploading problem

How can I solve it?  The classical input type="file" is not working with ASP.NET AJAX.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe classic input type=file does not work within an AJAX UpdatePanel as the file does not get posted to the server. You can get around this by using a PostBackTrigger (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/simpleajaxupload.aspx).

I'm afraid I'm not sure about why it won't work in DNN.

Comment: It worked. Simple, non-asynchronous, but it works. Thank you for the link.